# How many words between phrases in text?

Tags: elasticsearch, distance

I have a question, how count word between phrases in text? For example, I have the next text:

> Elon Musk is a technology entrepreneur and investor. He is the founder, CEO, and lead designer of SpaceX. Elon Musk has stated that the goals of SpaceX, Tesla, and SolarCity revolve around his vision to change the world and humanity.

And I want to count how many words are between "Elon Mask" and "SpaceX" or between "SolarCity" and "Tesla". How can I do it in Elastic search in a frame of one document?

Comment: May you please clarify your use case a bit? Do you need to know how far two phrases are in the document? How do you plan to use this information?

Comment: I wanna find a connection between persons, organizations in a text. The idea is if the two phrases are not far from each other in the text they usually use together, so there is some connection between them

Answer (score 0):

Below is what I've come up with.

**Mapping**

You would need to ensure that the field is of type `keyword` and you would make use of a term query using the `id` field of that document, so that the below logic would be applied only on that document.

I've created a sample mapping consisting of a single multi-field `myfield` as follows:

```
{  
   "myfield":{  
      "type":"text",
      "fields":{  
         "keyword":{  
            "type":"keyword",
            "ignore_above":256
         }
      }
   }
}
```

**Query**

I've made use of [Script Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-script-query.html) and [Sum Aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-sum-aggregation.html) to count the words between two phrases.

```
POST <your_index_name>/_search
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "_id": "1"
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "wordCount": {
      "sum": {
        "script": {
          "source": """
            String st = doc['myfield.keyword'].value.toString();
            if(st.contains(params.phrase_1) && st.contains(params.phrase_2)){
              int start = st.indexOf(params.phrase_1);
              int end = st.indexOf(params.phrase_2);

              //Substring would have list of words that includes phrase_1 till index of phrase_2
              String subString = st.substring(start,end);

              //Count tokens available in params.phrase_1
              StringTokenizer tokens_phrase_1 = new StringTokenizer(params.phrase_1);

              //Count total tokens available in substring
              StringTokenizer tokens = new StringTokenizer(subString);

              //Count = Count of Words - Count of words in phrase_1
              return tokens.countTokens()-tokens_phrase_1.countTokens();
            }else{
              //defensive logic
              return 0;
            }
          """,
          "params":{
            "phrase_1": "Elon Musk",
            "phrase_2": "SpaceX"

          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Notice that the inputs are in the `params` section. I've added some comments in the above code that would help in understanding as how I've added logic of calculating words.

Please test this and let me know if this helps!

Comment: hello @m-k, was the above query useful? Did it help you?